# Xamarin Studio doesn't build packages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin-studio

I'm having a little project (https://sourceforge.net/projects/audiocuesheet/) which I build with xamarin studio (project is plattform independent. Now I wanted to build a new test version with Packages in xamarin studio, but xamarin doesn't go on, the output of the Tool is just:

```
Creating packages

Package: Archive of Binaries

Building solution: AudioCuesheetEditor (Release Windows (x86)|x86)
```

And that's all. No error is reported but no package is build. I checked the path, it is valid, the project can be build using xamarin's normal build process also. Does anybody use the packages inside xamarin studio and can tell me, what is going wrong? Thanks in advance.

I could find the Xamarin logfile and there is an exception when building with the tool:

```
ERROR [2017-02-16 09:25:31Z]: An unhandled exception has occured. Terminating Xamarin Studio? False
System.Threading.SynchronizationLockException: Die Objektsynchronisationsmethode wurde von einem nicht synchronisierten Codeblock aufgerufen.
   at System.Threading.Monitor.ObjPulse(Object obj)
   at System.Threading.Monitor.Pulse(Object obj)
   at MonoDevelop.Ide.DispatchService.GtkSynchronizationContext.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.<Send>b__0(Object , EventArgs ) in C:\data\lanes\3510\0ccfcd52\source\monodevelop\main\src\core\MonoDevelop.Ide\MonoDevelop.Ide\DispatchService.cs:Zeile 68.
   at Gtk.Application.InvokeCB.Invoke()
   at GLib.Timeout.TimeoutProxy.Handler()
```

Does anybody have an idea, what is going wrong?

Comment: This looks like a bug in Xamarin Studio v6. Xamarin Studio 5.10 seems to be OK. I think you filed this on Xamarin's bugzilla.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is currently a bug in xamarin (https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=52559). The solution is to use version 5.10 (https://dl.xamarin.com/studio/Windows/XamarinStudio-5.10.3.51-0.msi)